# Class body - Call function to instantiate variable (unhandled exception type)

Tags: java

I'm having a small issue with my java code.

```
public class test {

static char[] pass = getMac(); // getting error on this line

public static char[] getMac() throws UnknownHostException
    {
        ...code...

        return x;
    }

}
```

I am already throwing the exception in the method but i'm getting the error on this line too :

```
static char[] pass = getMac(); // getting error on this line
```

> `unhandled Exception Type : unknownHostException`

is there any way to fix this ?

Thanks

I have tried :

```
try
{
   static char[] pass = getMac();
}
catch (UnknownHostException e)
{
   .....
}
```

but it doesn't work in the main class .

Answer (score 1):

> I am already throwing the exception in the method...

Right. That's the problem. By saying that the method throws that exception, you're forcing the calling code to handle it. Java's class initialization code isn't going to handle it for you, so you're getting an unhandled exception error.

Either handle it in the method, or defer initializing that static field until a time when you *can* handle it*. Note that *static initializer blocks* are allowed to include flow logic, so that's also an option.

Handling it in the method:

```
public static char[] getMac()
{
    try {
        // ...
        return x;
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) {
        // Appropriate handling
        return null; // Or whatever's appropriate
    }
}
```

Using a static initializer block:

```
public class test {

    static char[] pass;

    static {
        try {
            // ...
            pass = x;
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // Appropriate handling
            pass = null; // Or whatever's appropriate
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks , i used a try/catch in the method and it works